# SciFi story about "hive mind" babies that are born around the same time in a village

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking to re-read a SciFi short story about some "hive mind" babies that are born around the same time in a village... A similar plot to John Wyndham's *The Midwich Cuckoos*, but quite different. The babies never grow up or learn to walk. And they eventually all leave home and live together in an insect-like colony, crawling through underground tunnels (that I think they must have somehow created themselves). Not sure whether I read it in an old anthology or else an early SciFi magazine. It was probably written in the 1950s. Possibly earlier. Can't remember what it was that caused the babies to be born that way. (Cosmic radiation? Nuclear accident?)

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please review our [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any additional information you can think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Philip K. Dick's "The Crawlers." [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crawlers_(short_story))

Comment: Please edit your question to include the essential information from the link.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You mean "answer"?

Comment: Thanks! (Definitely sounds like it was "The Crawlers")